# Setting refresh interval in Elasticsearch to improve io-wait?

Tags: elasticsearch

My cluster shows a lot of io-waits (about 50%).

I do a lot of indexing and reindexing.

I thought maybe the re-indexing of lucene is the cause of much IO. Thought of maybe upping the refresh_interval or maybe the index.translog options - is that the right way to go?

My main problem is I do not know how to find out what my setting are.

In http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/ it lists alot of options, none of which are available when I use:

```
curl -xget 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings'
```

It does not return values if using the defaults (According to kimchy's answer on [this post](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Changing-the-refresh-interval-on-running-nodes-td3020559.html#a4037476))

I only get the number of shards, replicas, which i set explicitly. 
The elasticsearch.yml file does not tell what the defaults are. How would I know my changes took places, and what are the values now?

Help much appreciated as I cant find documentation for this.

running hot_threads, I got:

```
> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads?threads=5'
::: [Gardener][CR0qQbtBRyeU94hltnnE7A][inet[/10.154.148.151:9300]]{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}

   50.6% (253.2ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gardener][search][T#20]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 8 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   32.9% (164.5ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gardener][search][T#12]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 8 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   29.1% (145.5ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gardener][search][T#8]'
     2/10 snapshots sharing following 20 elements
       org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryWrapperFilter.getDocIdSet(MultiTermQueryWrapperFilter.java:111)
       org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantWeight.scorer(ConstantScoreQuery.java:131)
       org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery$RandomAccessFilterStrategy.filteredScorer(FilteredQuery.java:533)
       org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery$1.scorer(FilteredQuery.java:133)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:609)
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:161)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:572)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:524)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:501)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:127)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:141)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:206)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:193)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:179)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
     8/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   26.5% (132.7ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gardener][search][T#11]'
     2/10 snapshots sharing following 15 elements
       org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:161)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:572)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:524)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:501)
       org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
       org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:127)
       org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:239)
       org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteQuery(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:141)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:80)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:206)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:193)
       org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:179)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
     8/10 snapshots sharing following 8 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    4.2% (21.1ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[Gardener][bulk][T#4]'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 9 elements
       sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
       java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:706)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:615)
       org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1109)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Running with block and wait:

```
> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads?threads=3&type=wait'
::: [Gardener][CR0qQbtBRyeU94hltnnE7A][inet[/10.154.148.151:9300]]{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) wait usage by thread 'Reference Handler'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 3 elements
       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
       java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
       java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) wait usage by thread 'Finalizer'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 4 elements
       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
       java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) wait usage by thread 'Signal Dispatcher'
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads?threads=3&type=block'
::: [Gardener][CR0qQbtBRyeU94hltnnE7A][inet[/10.154.148.151:9300]]{aws_availability_zone=us-east-1d}

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) block usage by thread 'Reference Handler'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 3 elements
       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
       java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
       java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) block usage by thread 'Finalizer'
     10/10 snapshots sharing following 4 elements
       java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
       java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
       java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

    0.0% (0s out of 500ms) block usage by thread 'Signal Dispatcher'
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
     unique snapshot
```

Comment: just to make things clear for anyone that tries this in the future. the setting is `"refresh_interval":-1` if you want to disable. But to enable back it needs to be a string with units. so that 60 seconds would be `"refresh_interval":"60s"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, `index.refresh_interval` is set to 1s. You can increase this interval or disable automatic refresh by setting it to -1.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : -1
    }
}
'
```

However, before you start messing with settings I would suggest figuring out the actual reason for such high I/O. Run [hot_threads](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-nodes-hot-threads/) request and check where threads are spending most of the time.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried upping the refresh interval to 5s - did not seem to help.
I ran the hot_threads request - and updated the question. Can you help me read this? What is sun.misc.Unsafe.park?

Comment: Oh, it's in aws! What are you using for storage?

Comment: EBS external non-root drive

Comment: If it's not striped EBS make it striped and if possible switch to provisioned "IOPS".

Comment: Will do on the provisioned. What does striped mean? I just read about it a little, isnt this relevant only when using more than one volume?

Comment: Can you explain to me how to interpret the hot_threads output? What am I to understand from this?

Comment: Correct, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html for info about EBS. I hoped that hot_threads will show something interesting (sometimes it's possible to see threads stuck in some operations). In your case I don't really see anything interesting there - just a couple of threads doing search.